# RabbitMQ - How to maintain Connection and Channel when one node is shut down?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I connected to two rabbit server using CreateConnection(IList hostnames) C# function.

[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN5U5.jpg)

But connection node was one and when I shut down this rabbit server the connection disappeared. I expected that because another node maintains a connection, clustering is needed. Did I misunderstand?